# How can I change each name of icon in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I loaded images from gallery and put touchable opacity expo vector icon on each image.
When I click Image, i want to change icon name of that image.
like `<FontAwesom name="circle-o" size={24} color:"black"/>` to `<FontAwesome name="circle" size={24} color:"black"/>`

I tried `<FontAwesome name={selectedMultiple.map(item => item.id === photo.id ? "circle" : "circle-o"} size={24} color="black"/>`  but it is error.

here is my part of code

```
    const [selectedMultiplePhoto, setSeletedMultiplePhoto] = useState([]);
    const removeItem = (arr, obj) => {
        const result = arr.filter(item => item.id !== obj.id);
        setSeletedMultiplePhoto(result);
    };

    const toMultiple = (photo) => {
        const singlePhoto = {...photo};

        setIsSelected(prev => !prev);

        const isSameItem =  selectedMultiplePhoto.filter((item, index) => {
            return item.id === photo.id;
        });
        if(isSameItem.length <= 0) {
            setSeletedMultiplePhoto([singlePhoto, ...selectedMultiplePhoto]);
        }else{
            if(selectedMultiplePhoto.length === 1){
                Alert.alert("should select at least 1 image");
                return 0;
            }
            removeItem(selectedMultiplePhoto, singlePhoto);
        }
    };
    ...
    ...
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection:"row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
        {allPhotos.map(photo => (
            // this part is image gallery part
            ...
            ...
                {isMultiple ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={customStyles.select} onPress={() => toMultiple(photo)}>
                        <FontAwesome name={selectedMultiple.map(item => item.id === photo.id ? "circle" : "circle-o"} size={24} color="black"/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : (
                    null
                ) }
                ...

        ))}
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Map returns an array. You need to get one element. Change it to:  name={selectedMultiple.find(item => item.id === photo.id) ?  "circle" : "circle-o"}

Comment: Thanx!! I worked!!